# MVC ASP.Net Application which can read message by GSM Module?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arduino, gps, gsm

I am Computer Science Student, working on Final Year Project based on Vehicle Tracking and Accident Detection. I have completed my hardware part, now I have to create a Web based application on MVC ASP.Net, I have done my database part but now I am stuck in that when Accident detected, GPS track the location and GSM will send the coordinates of location to Web Application ASP.Net. Now I need to read that message sent by GSM and show it on Web Application. I have also placed another GSM module at the Web Application end that receives the message.
    At message receiving end, I have connected GSM module with Arduino, I can read message through Ardunio IDE Serial Monitor, but now I want the same Serial Monitor on my Web Based MVC ASP.Net Application, which can automatically detects the port on which Arduino is connected and automatically read and display the Message received by GSM module.
HARDWARE DETAILS:
Arduino UNO
GSM 900a
GPS U-blox NEO 6M